# AngularJS filtering ng-repeat OR on multiple fields

Tags: angularjs, filter

How can I filter one search term on different fields combining them in an OR statement?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in persons| filter:filters{surname: 'foo' OR name: 'foo'}">
        {{person}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: create a custom filter introducing your condition inside, you will have to pass both perso.surname and person.name 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters
, its better to not give it ready its easy try it

Comment: Have you tried <li ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-if="person.surname ==='foo' || person.name==='foo' ">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either filter by **all properties** of each object with `| filter:'foo'`, or create a **custom filter**, e.g.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.persons=[
    {"id":1,"name":"foo","surname":"bar"},
    {"id":2,"name":"baz","surname":"foo"},
    {"id":3,"name":"null","surname":"undefined"},
    {"id":4,"name":"name","surname":"surname"}
  ]
});
app.filter('searchBy', function() {
  return function(array, param) {
    var new_array = [];
    angular.forEach(array, function(value) {
      if (value.name == param || value.surname == param) { // your filter query in here
        new_array.push(value);
      }
    })
    return new_array;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in persons| searchBy:'foo'">
      {{person}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```